# React.js app cross-origin request blocked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firefox, cors

I put my react.js application on the server. Almost everything works fine. However, I have a question, I am still a beginner. The contact form does not work in any browser. I tested it multiple times in Firefox Developer Edition and Chrome. The following errors appear. How to resolve these CORS errors? Is the problem that there is still a localhost address on port 5000 that has not been changed to an address with the domain?

[image: Errors]

Comment: You need to set your React app deployment url to your server api cors header to allow it. That will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's a fairly common internet security concept that essentially prevents a site from using assets from another site without permission. Have a read of the concept here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

What you are trying to access (I assuming is your own resources on your own server) was not returning the following in the HTTP response header

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

That header means the server where the resource is hosted is okay with the resource being used anywhere. No matter what browser you use, CORS is implemented in the same way. This would be more of a server issue than with the browser.